# How to Reccurently Transpose A Series/List/Array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list

I have a array/list/pandas series :

```
np.arange(15)
Out[11]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14])
```

What I want is:

```
[[0,1,2,3,4,5],
[1,2,3,4,5,6],
[2,3,4,5,6,7],
...
[10,11,12,13,14]]
```

That is, recurently transpose this columns into a 5-column matrix.

The reason is that I am doing feature engineering for a column of temperature data. I want to use last 5 data as features and the next as target.

What's the most efficient way to do that? my data is large.

Comment: Is it necessary to create a matrix? How about doing a rolling window instead?

Comment: I want matrix, as many things can be done with matrix.

Comment: Use generators - use itertools recipes.

Comment: @wwii More specifically?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service.   You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer for solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the array is formatted like this :

```
arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,....])
```

You could try it like this :

```
recurr_transpose = np.matrix([[arr[i:i+5] for i in range(len(arr)-4)]])
```